# Filtering data based on dropdown select Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a blade view where i have a dropdown select where it has all the `Subject` that is from the database and a date picker where i can select the start date and end date. Using the selections that i have selected from the dropdown select and date picker, I would like to filter the data of my `Attendance` table and display it as a PDF table. So far from what i am able to accomplish is to extract ALL the data and display as PDF. How can i create this filter function? I am relatively still new to laravel so pardon me for asking such question.

This is what i have done so far.

**GenerateReportController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Attendance;
use PDF;

class GenerateReportController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $subjects = Subject::all(['id','s_name']);

        //$attendance = Attendance::all();
        return View::make('generate', compact('subjects',$subjects));
    }

    public function downloadPDF()
    {
        $report = Attendance::all();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf',compact('report'));
        $name = "Attendance Report";
        return $pdf->stream($name.'.pdf');
    }
}
```

**pdf.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Attendance Report</title>
</head>
<body>   
    <h1>Attendance Report</h1>    
    <p>Generated by {{Auth::user()->name}}</p>
    <p>Date Generated : {{ date('Y-m-d') }}</p>
    <p>Time Generated : {{ date('h:i:s a')}}</p>
    <table cellpadding="10">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Time</th> 
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($report as $repo)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$repo->student->stud_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$repo->subject->s_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$repo->date}}</td>
                <td>{{$repo->time}}</td>
                <td>{{$repo->att_status}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED**

**generate.blade.php**

The form is it helps filter the data based on the subject i have selected then it would generate a PDF with the results from my `attendance` table based on the subject name `s_name` when i click on Generate Report. How can i accomplish that?

```
@extends('master')

@section('page_header')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="page-title">Attendance Records</h1>
    <a href="/dashboard/attendance/report/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="voyager-list" style="font-size:15px;"></i>
    <span>Generate Report</span>
    </a>
</div>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::Label('subject', 'Subject:')!!}
    <select class="form-control" name="s_name">
        @foreach($subjects as $subject)
        <option value="{{$subject->s_name}}">{{$subject->s_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
        <br>
        {!! Form::Label('startDate', 'Start Date:') !!}<br>
        {!! Form::input('date', 'startDate', null, ['class' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'dd/mm/yy']) !!}
        <br>
        <br>
        {!! Form::Label('endDate', 'End Date:') !!}<br>
        {!! Form::input('date', 'endDate', null, ['class' => 'datepicker', 'data-date-format' => 'dd/mm/yy']) !!}
</div>        
@endsection

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.date').datepicker({  
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    orientation: 'bottom'
    });  

</script>
```

**web.php**

`Route::get('dashboard/attendance/generate','GenerateReportController@index');` 
`Route::get('dashboard/attendance/report','GenerateReportController@downloadPDF');`

Comment: create a form with filter options and submit it to `downloadPDF()` method. process as per the filter. If you have a from add it here.

Comment: The problem is i am unsure of how do i create the form sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## try this:

```
    $whereRawKeys = '';
    $whereRawValues = [];
    $report = new Attendance();
    $rquestQueries = [
        'Date(attendances.date)' => $request->get('date'), // datepacker input from date
        'attendances.student_id' => $request->get('student_id'), // select student name given student id
        'attendances.subject_id' => $request->get('subject_id') // select subject name given subject id
    ];

    foreach ($rquestQueries as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_null($value) && $value != '') {
            $whereRawKeys .= ($key . ' = ? AND ');
            $whereRawValues = array_merge($whereRawValues, [$value]);
        }
    }

    $whereRawKeys = substr($whereRawKeys, 0, -4);
    $report = $report->whereRaw($whereRawKeys, $whereRawValues);
    $report->leftJoin('students', 'students.id', '=', 'attendances.student_id')
    ->leftJoin('subjects', 'subjects.id', '=', 'attendances.subject_id');

    $report = $report->selectRaw('attendances.*, students.stud_name, subjects.s_name')->get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', compact('report'));
```

Comment: i am getting an error `Undefined variable: request` and may i ask how would i do for the form for filtering the data?